# Can an stdout stream from a desktop app be directed at a Chrome extension or app?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have an older desktop program that I am trying to integrate with a web interface. The program can export a data stream of XML directly to stdout and can accept simple commands through the Windows command line to trigger this.

Is there a way to send commands to the Windows command line from a Chrome extension or app?

For instance, I can send the following command and it will send the output stream to a program:

```
MakeExport history /format:xml /target:stdout > SomeApp.exe
```

Is there a way to receive the stdout stream provided by the desktop program to my Chrome extension?

Answer (score 1):

No, not directly in arbitrary format.

You can, however, write a proxy app that will communicate with Chrome using [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging).

Chrome will have to initiate the connection / run the host app. Your proxy will call your legacy app, reformat the response, and send it back to Chrome.